# jQuery event trigger - cancelable event

Tags: jquery

I have created a jquery plugin which is triggering an event:

```
$.fn.myplugin = function(options) {
    this.on("foo.myplugin", options.foo);
    this.on("bar.myplugin", options.bar);
};
```

I want to check if foo has been canceled by a user and prevent bar from being triggered:

```
// trigger foo
this.trigger("foo.myplugin");

// how do I check if foo was canceled
if( !fooCanceled ) {
    this.trigger("bar.myplugin");
}
```

How can I check if foo was canceled to prevent bar from being triggered?

jQuery UI does something similar to this, but it did not work when I tried:

```
if (this._trigger("search", event) === false) {
    return;
}
```

I tried something similar to this:

```
if( this.trigger("foo.myplugin") === false ) {
    return;
}

this.trigger("bar.myplugin");
```

But bar was still being triggered.

I am initializing my plugin like so:

```
$("#asdf").myplugin({
    foo: function(event) {
        // cancel the event
        event.preventDefault();
    },

    bar: function(event) {
        console.log("should not be triggered");
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you try `this._trigger('foo.myplugin') === false`?

Comment: I was under the impression that _trigger was jQuery UI, which I am not using. I was just using their code as an example.

Comment: Can you define what being *cancelled by the user* means?

Comment: @rae1n Sure. Lets say I have a close and closing event on a dialog, etc. The closing event gives the user a chance to prevent the close event from happening, maybe by throwing up a confirmation box asking them if they are sure they want to close. If they choose not to close, it will not fire the close handler, only the closing. That is what I mean by canceling the event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following this pattern might allow you to accomplish what you're after.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/VzzLf/3/

**JS**

```
//Plugin structure from : http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring
(function( $ ){

  var methods = {
     init : function( options ) {

       return this.each(function(){
           var ele = $(this); 

           ele.on('click.myPlugin', function(e){

               //Hold a reference to the event
               var event = $.Event("closing")

               //Trigger it on the element
               ele.trigger(event); 

               //Check to see if it was disabled
               if(!event.isDefaultPrevented()){
                   ele.trigger('close');
               }

           }); 

       });

     }
  };

  $.fn.myPlugin = function( method ) {

    if ( methods[method] ) {
      return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
      return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
    } else {
      $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.myPlugin' );
    }    

  };

})( jQuery );

  $(function(){
      $('#myPlugin')
          .myPlugin()
          .on('closing', function(){
            alert('closing');      
          })
          .on('close', function(){
            alert('close fired');      
          });   
      $('#myPluginDisabled')
          .myPlugin()
          .on('closing', function(e){
              alert('Disable close'); 
              e.preventDefault(); 
          })
          .on('close', function(e){
              alert('Will never get here'); 
          });      
  }); 
​
```

**HTML**

```
<div id='myPlugin'>Click me I'm enabled</div>

<div id='myPluginDisabled'>Click me I'm disabled</div>​
```